# Extract name from folder and use it powershell

Tags: powershell, extract

i have to build a script in powershell that does those tasks:

- read the name of the the folder (example GRA - First Man on Mars)
- extract the name of the folder before the "-" character and store into a variable named "shop"
- copy a sample folder named "2021" with subfolders and files into the first folder "ex. GRA - First man on mars)
- enter into the folder (GRA - first man on mars) and rename the excel file from "sample.xlsx" to "shop - sample.xlsx
- move to the second folder
  The script must repeat the same operations for all the first level folders.

i tried some script in batch, but i think that i have to move to powershell...

first step:
i tried to read the name of the folder with this:

`Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Directory | Select Name,
@{ n = 'Foldername'; e = { ($_.PSPath -split "-")[1] } }`

but i have to extract the left part of the name, not the right part.

Comment: Powershell can run bash scripts. At any case, I'd suggest posting what you have tried, and taking a look at the [Microsoft guide to powershell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/modules/introduction-to-powershell/)

Comment: `Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Directory | Select Name, @{ n = 'Foldername'; e = { ($_.Name -Split "-")[0] } }` would make more sense than using `$_.PSPath`. You're not providing a `-Path` to `Get-ChildItem` so the current directory will be used by default and therefore its `Name` property will still be propagated as normal.

Comment: the first step work! thanks @Compo

Answer (score 0):

Approach it like this:

1. Get a list of the folders
2. For each folder..
3. Parse the name
4. Copy the Content
5. Rename the file

```
$sampleDirectory = Get-Item -Path C:\PathTo\yourSample\Directory
$Folders = Get-ChildItem -Directory -Path C:\PathTo\YourFolders
ForEach ($folder in $folders){
   $folderName = $_.Name.Split("-")[0]
   Copy-Item $sampleDirectory -Destination $folder

   #Play with the syntax here to get your ideal name
   $desiredName = $folderName + "whatever.xls"
   Get-Item $folder\sample.xls | Rename-Item -NewName $desiredName -WhatIf
}
```

This should get you going

Comment: the right command is "$sampleDirectory = Get-ChildItem -Path C:\PathTo\yourSample\Directory\*"
now the second step works!

Comment: I changed line 1 from `Get-ChildItem` to `Get-item`, sorry it was a typo!

Comment: sorry but now the error is:
Invalid operation:
You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
what does it mean?

Comment: If the folder doesn't have a dash, you would have tht error.  Maybe one of the folders doesn't have a dash in its name!